# how do I display Quick Edit box on a custom plugin page with a list of posts?

Tags: quick-edit

I have put together a simple plugin that connects to Google Analytics API to display a list of popular posts from a year ago in wp-admin. I would like to display the Quick Edit box for each post to add a tag to them. How do I go about that?

I only can find information on how to add a custom field to the Quick Edit box. I don't need a custom field, just a regular, standard Quick Edit box.

I have

```
// Enqueue necessary scripts for Quick Edit functionality
function enqueue_quick_edit_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  }
  add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_quick_edit_scripts');
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="edit-post-quick-edit" data-post-id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">  <?php echo $post->post_title; ?></td></a>
```

then I know I need to use jquery in the footer,

```
  // Add "Quick Edit" functionality to the posts list
$('.edit-post-quick-edit').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var postId = $(this).data('post-id');
  console.log (postId);
  inlineEditPost.edit(postId); 
});
```

However, I get "inlineEditPost is not defined". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @Natalia, It's been some months already but no answer of your question, I'm also looking for this and couldn't find any good solution even any code. Do you have any update how did you manage that please?

Comment: No, I was not able to have a Quick Edit box displayed on a custom WP admin page. If you really need it, I suggest to look in WP source code. I did a workaround, where the list of my posts opens in a new window with the default Wordpress display and Quick Edit behaviour.